# how to get the url of a list item in jslink?

Tags: jslink, list-view-web-part

I am using the jslink code below to display the title of the list in a List View web part as a hyperlink. But the problem is that I don't know how to point to the url of that item? so how can I get the url of that item so that when the user clicks on it it will redirect him to the display page as it normally done by default?

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = {};
    overrideContext.Templates.Header = "<ul id='local-news2'>"
    overrideContext.Templates.Item = CBody;
    overrideContext.Templates.Footer = "</ul>"
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();

function CBody(ctx) {

    var ret =  "<li>" +
                     "<a href='" + url here + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</a>" +
                "</li>";
    return ret; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this. The url will take you to the display form of the item.

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = {};
    overrideContext.Templates.Header = "<ul id='local-news2'>"
    overrideContext.Templates.Item = CBody;
    overrideContext.Templates.Footer = "</ul>"
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();

function CBody(ctx) {
    var url = String.format('{0}&amp;ID={1}', ctx.displayFormUrl, ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
    var ret =  "<li>" +
                     "<a href='" + url + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</a>" +
                "</li>";
    return ret; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can format your URL as below

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/YOUR_LISTNAME_HERE/DispForm.aspx?ID=ITEM_ID_HERE"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my SharePoint-Site (SP-Online) I am using following (by JSLink connected) script for achieving your demand:

```
(function () {
    var globalOverrideCtx = {
        Templates: {
            Fields: {
                'LinkToPicture':{
                    'View': GetLinkOfItem
                }
            }
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(globalOverrideCtx);
})();


function GetLinkOfItem(ctx)

{
    var ret

    if (!ctx.CurrentItem.LinkToPicture) {
        ret = "<a href='" + JSON.stringify(ctx.CurrentItem.FileRef).replace(/['"]+/g, '') + "'>" + "Item Link" + "</a>" 


    }

    return ret;
}
```

You only need to additionally create a SharePoint-Column (I used Text-Column) with the RealFieldName: "LinkToPicture"

My Output:

[image]